# UILocalNotification Minimal Actions – One Blue, One Clear?

Tags: ios, push-notification, uilocalnotification

I’m screwing around with `UILocalNotification` and notification actions – all working as I’d expect, except that when I provide the two `Minimal` actions in my category, when revealing the actions via a swipe in the Notification Center, the right-most action is always blue.

Since the actions in my app are equal, I’d rather them both be the clear grey colour, rather than one blue, one clear. I know that I can make them both red with `destructive`, but that’s wrong too, and if I explicitly set `destructive` to `false`, I still get one blue, one clear.

Here’s an image showing what I’m talking about:

[image]

And here’s the code I used to make it:

```
let note = UILocalNotification()

note.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5)
note.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()

note.alertBody = "Actions: A and B"
note.alertTitle = "Notification!"

let action1 = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
action1.identifier = “ACTION_A"
action1.title = "A"
action1.activationMode = .Background

let action2 = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
action2.identifier = “ACTION_B"
action2.title = "B"
action2.activationMode = .Background

let category = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
category.identifier = "ANSWERS_CATEGORY"
category.setActions([action1, action2], forContext: .Default)

note.category = “ACTIONS_CATEGORY"

let categories = Set(arrayLiteral: category)
let settingsRequest = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Sound, .Badge], categories: categories)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settingsRequest)

UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(note)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both the [HiG](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/NotificationCenter.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH39-SW1) and the [notification programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1) do not suggest that is possible to set the buttons' background colour. The most specific reference I found is in the latter, that states:

> If the destructive property is NO, the action’s button appears blue; if it’s YES, the button is red.

This is obviously not precise, since two non-destructive actions are not both blue, but it implicitly suggests that the colour for each is automatically set by iOS

Comment: Let’s hope we have a little more than implication to go on – but thanks for digging that up.

Comment: Looks like this is correct, and my only options are to live with it, or make them both red ;)